# using variables assingned in the script inside the proc in TCL

Tags: tcl, proc

i want to use the variable assigned outside  (proc) to be used inside the proc . For example i tried the following thing

```
set a 10
proc myproc { } {
puts $a
}
myproc
```

I am expecting the above script to print 10 . But the above script is erroring out "can't read "a": no such variable"

I cannot pass $a as argument to script because i have lot such variables i want to use inside my proc inside my script . Could you please help me to solve this problem ?

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is declared at the same stack level as the call to `myproc` then you can do following in your proc:

```
upvar a a
```

like this:

```
set a 10
proc myproc { } {
    upvar a a
    puts $a
}
myproc
```

and then you can use `$a` locally in the procedure. The `upvar` command "links" a variable declared somewhere in the stack with a local variable. If the variable is declared more than 1 level deeper in the stack, thn you need to pass "2" to `upvar`, so it knows where to look for the variable:

```
upvar 2 a a
```

If you don't pass the "2" (or other value), the `upvar` assumes default lookup depth of 1.

You can read more details about `upvar` in Tcl documentation for that command.

If the variable `a` is always a global variable (declared at the script top level), then you can use:

```
global a
```

in your procedure, instead of `upvar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have namespaces you could always assign it there :

```
namespace eval blah { 
    variable a 10 
}

proc blah::myproc { } {
    variable a
    puts $a
}
blah::myproc
```

This way you can avoid potential collisions with other global variables